# How to model an optional breakdown of a column

Tags: database, database-design, olap

I'm coming up with a design for a database that will allow queries over historic transactions, and I'm stumped with this particular issue.

One of the columns to be stored is, let's say, number of sales per day (to be broken down by a variety of attributes).  With recent data, we can break this down into online and in-store sales; however, before a certain cut-off the only information available to populate this database is the total sales figure, without the breakdown.

I can't think of a particularly elegant way to present this, such that newer data can populate the logical "Online Sales" and "In-store sales" columns, with "Total Sales" being computed as their sum (in a view/sproc/computed column) - and yet old data can just report the total sales figure.

FWIW clients of this data will be aware that the sales breakdown may or may not be there - so the output of a query would always have a valid "Total sales" figure, and might have missing values for online or in-store sales.  (I specifically say "missing" instead of "null" as there's no strong requirement to have it represented as such, if an alternative makes more sense.)

Is there a canonical way to handle this situation?

---

Given a lack of strong responses so far, I'll post a few answers of my own that I see as candidates (I may end up needing to accept one of them anyway if no superior answers materialise).  Comments, criticism and or votes on these are graciously accepted - and especially improvements to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third approach is to model sales figures as a many-to-one relationship with the observed fact; that is, each fact contains multiple (possibly just one) sales figures, each with a particular type.  In this case, the total sales would just a be sum of whatever figures were present.

So the schema might look like

```
DataFact
-------------
DataFactId (PK)
(+any other fact columns apart from sales)

SalesData
---------
DataFactId (FK to DataFact)
SalesDataType ("Total"/"Online" etc - either as varchar or FK to dimension table)
SalesValue (the actual sales figure we want to record)
```

Advantages of this approach are that it captures the concept that for a given fact, it may or may not contain any particular sales data entity.  It also abstracts out just the field that varies, meaning that any common fields are still just expressed once in the parent DataFact table (unlike with [separate fact tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393182/45664)).  It's also trivial to expand if there are additional breakdowns of sales available in future.

Disadvantages are that it still doesn't express the constraint that either total or online + in-store must exist.  In fact we can't even express that at least one SalesData entry must exist; this has the same issues as adding multiple nullable fields.  And while this approach is quite neat, to make best use of its flexibility we'd want to give the sales data back to the querying client as some sort of collection, which makes querying more complex than just a standard 2D result set.  It *could* be compressed back down into a 2D table using aggregation over the `SalesData` table, but I believe you'd have to pull it in multiple times with different constraints to determine each field.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the difference between an **OLTP** and an **OLAP** database.

**OLTP** (**On Line Transaction Processing**) This type of data represents day to day transactions. For example inventory additions, changes deletions. Customer add to cart requests, orders, refunds. These are the nitty gritty transactions that occur all day long.

**OLAP** (**On Line Analytical Processing**) this type of data represents accumulated data over given periods of time. For example: daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly, annualy. Buy storing this information in a separate set of tables or even database you can run different queries to give you the reporting you are looking for.

The problem you can run into is when you want OLAP information when all you have is OLTP data.

If you want daily sales by separate categories then create a set of daily OLAP tables and each night run a separate process or set of processes that archive that data off into these tables.

Each month you can run a different process to create monthly OLAP tables.

It's quite a bit of work at first but it gives you the best of both world. You can play what if games all day long against your OLAP data without impacting customers or the day to day operations.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely an OLAP-oriented database I'm designing.  But I feel your answer doesn't quite cover the case of exactly *how* to model the case that for some months I can supply `Online sales` and `In-store sales` (and want a total calculated off that), but in other months I just have `total sales`.  Should there be three nullable columns in the OLAP fact table?  Two "subclasses" of fact table?  A one-to-many relationship between a fact and the `(Sales figure type, value)` tuples associated with it?

Comment: In fact I've just added an answer to represent each of these techniques that I've been considering, I'd appreciate your thoughts on which one makes the most sense for OLAP data, and how you might improve any of them.

Comment: Why do some months only have total sales and not a breakdown between online and instore?

Comment: Because this data wasn't being captured at the time (and implicitly was not stored anywhere, so is now unknown).  But we do still want to include the aggregate data from this earlier period in the timeseries offered up for querying, especially as most of the time clients won't care about the breakdown.

Comment: Would it skew the numbers if you took the average percentage of online sales (from when you did start capturing this data) and split out the older data using this percentage?

Comment: It wouldn't *skew* them such as it would be making up data, which seems like anathema for an app that's meant to be reporting on data that we do have.  In these cases the returned value ought to be something like `null` (and the presentation layer should just reflect that a breakdown isn't available for those dates, but we don't have to worry about that here).

Answer (score 0):

i would perhaps add a "sales version" table that would allow to distinguish between "historic non breakable sales" and "newer sales".

So , maybe this kind of structure can be achieved:

sales_version table

columns : salesid,salesversion

sales_v1 table

columns: salesid,datetime

i suppose for each sale , the details are in a slave table that refers the salesid

sales_v2 table

columns: salesid,datetime,online,instore or perhaps salesid,datetime,type ('online' or 'instore') or a type id that itselfs refer to a sales type table.

i suppose for each sale , the details are in a slave table that refers the salesid

Answer (score 0):

One approach is simply to have all three columns present on the fact table, and for them all to be nullable.  For the newer data just the two more specific sales data columns are populated, and for the older data just the total sales is populated.

When querying, the total sales value could be populated conditionally, something like:

```
CASE WHEN TotalSales IS NULL THEN OnlineSales + InStoreSales ELSE TotalSales END
```

This has the advantage of being the most simple from the application's perspective.  Though from a data-modelling perspective I don't like the fact that **every** record will leave at least one field null.  And it becomes difficult to express the data integrity constraint that *either* `TotalSales` is populated, *or* both of `OnlineSales` and `InStoreSales` must be populated.  Would checking this with a trigger be considered good practice?

(Alternative version to this is to populate the `TotalSales` field even in the new case, but I don't think the duplication and risk of potentially inconsistent data is worth the marginally simpler querying.)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach is to have two distinct fact tables, one each for the old and new data, and model these based on exactly what data can be determined in each case.

For querying, the overall result would be the union of data from both fact tables - with the select from the old fact table being padded with `NULL` (or similar) for the specific sales data columns.

This approach is nice because it accurately models what data we're recording (and able to record), but it potentially leads to a lot of duplication of fields if the two tables are identical except for the sales column(s).  Also, I have an (unqualified) feeling that it will be harder for the database to do useful things with indices when taking the union of two tables, such that query performance may suffer.